# double backslash for unicode in Strings when I output map to json using Gson

Tags: gson

I am trying to serialize my `LinkedHashMap<String,String>` to a json file using GSON

what I tried is this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

resultMap.put("xxxxx","\\u53D1\\u51FA\\u8BE5");

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create;

try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Desktop\\testGson.json")0{
    gson.toJson(resultMap, fileWriter);
} catch( IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want the output json value be like `\u53D1\u51fa\u8BE5` but for now the output json have double backslashes, basically the unescaped unicode.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are storing `\\u53D1\\u51FA\\u8BE5` in the map, that is, not the Unicode characters `发` (U+53D1), ... but instead the literal strings `\u53D1`, `\u51FA` and `\u8BE5`. Gson will output these in the JSON string, and escape the `\`, since otherwise it would change the value of the string (from `\u53D1` to `发` and so on).

Unfortunately there is currently no feature to force Gson to use Unicode escapes for non-ASCII characters (in case that is what you wanted), but as shown in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/388#issuecomment-83704872) you could provide a custom `java.io.Writer` which performs the escaping.

Answer (score 0):

This is always an option when the tool won't do the job:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create;
String json = gson.toJson(myClassInstance);
json = json.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\u","\\\\u");
// Write json string to file
```

This replaces all instances in json that have `\\u` with `\u`